# How to get these nested quotes to work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, escaping, greasemonkey

I'm trying to inject some Javascript code into a webpage using Greasemonkey. First I will start with what works.

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js";
$("#navHome").append( script );

var buttonCode ='<input type="button" value="Make public" onclick="var selector=\'div.timelineTimestamp\'; $(selector).each(function() { var textToAppend=\' <input type=\\\'button\\\' value=\\\'Make Public\\\' > \'; $(this).append(textToAppend) });">'


$("#navHome").append(buttonCode);
```

I'm trying to change the line for the buttonCode so that when the button is pressed an alert is displayed. But to insert an alert message requires me to go one more level down in quotes, and I can't find a way to make it work.

The closes I can get to it working is by inserting the following

```
onclick=\\\'alert(\\\\\'hi\\\\\')\\\'
```

but that still doesn't work. How can this be done?

Comment: You shouldn't write the code this way, if you use jquery bind events, instead inline code...

Comment: Also, if you have jQuery, why do you include it again? You probably don't need to.

Comment: Will binding even work? I think that Greasemonkey methods are protected and inaccessible from the outside.

Comment: jQuery is included in the Greasemonkey script, but whatever's inside the script is inaccessible from the outside, so I have to inject it directly into the webpage.

Comment: Oh, I missed the Greasemonkey part. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try building your elements using jQuery instead, like this:

```
$("#navHome").append($("<script />").attr("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"));

var buttonCallback = function() {
    // your callback code goes here...
};

$("#navHome").append($("<input />").attr("type", "button").val("Make public").bind("click", buttonCallback));
```

Comment: That didn't work. What is $("<script />") for? Is that supposed to find a script tag? There isn't one there.

Comment: $("<script />") creates a script dom element and wraps it with a jQuery object. What happens when you run this code? You get any error? Also, why would you include jQuery if you already seem to have it included?

Comment: Oh, seems like I forgot a parenthesis. I'll update the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You already have jQuery in your script, with a `@require` directive, otherwise `$("#navHome").append( script );` would not work.

So, don't inject jQuery into the target page.  Keep everything in the sandbox.  It will run faster with fewer complications.  Lose all of that `<script>` part and just use:

```
$("#navHome").append ('<button id="makePublicBtn">Make public</button>');

$("#makePublicBtn").click ( function () {
    var selector    = 'div.timelineTimestamp';
    $(selector).each (function () {
        var textToAppend    ='<input type="button" value="Make Public">';
        $(this).append (textToAppend);
    } );
} );
```

Note: use a `<button>` for a button, unless it is part of a form and you want the value transmitted.

Comment: Is this better than binding to a button?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Both this answer and vrutberg's bind the `click` event to a button (or an `<input>` masquerading as a button.)  The only key difference is that this answer eliminates an unwieldy and unnecessary injection of jQuery into the target page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonCode ="<input type=\"button\" value=\"Make public\" onclick=\"var selector='div.timelineTimestamp'; $(selector).each(function() { var textToAppend=' <input type=\"button\" value=\"Make Public\" > '; $(this).append(textToAppend) });\">";
```

notice where at the beginning and the end of the var declaration i replaced ' by " , and inside the declaration i added \"

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js";




$("#navHome").append( script );

var buttonCode ="<input type=\"button\" id=\"btnID\" value=\"Make public\" >"; 


$("#navHome").append(buttonCode);

$('#btnID').live('click',function(){  // get click event on dynamically created element
    $('div.timelineTimestamp').each(function() { 
        var textToAppend= "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Make Public\" > "; 
        $(this).append(textToAppend) ;
        });
});
```